# Jess Pardue has a wrong link!

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, stack-exchange-team

In https://stackexchange.com/about/team, if account is linked, it linked to network profile. Hers is uncaught exception - it links to MSE profile.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixed.

Give the cache 6-8 minutes to expire.

Comment: very fast... :D

Comment: Not if the cache is a 1 hour one, and not 5 minutes, as I recall ;)

Comment: Curious to know why some employees get a profile and some do not, e.g. [Natalie How](http://stackexchange.com/users/4540164/natalie-how) got a totally empty account. Is there some logic in who gets account and who doesn't?

Comment: Some people really don't need a profile... but if they have one, why not link it? @Sha

Comment: So you say Natalie had a profile before starting to work for Stack Exchange?

Comment: :O they don't like the fix, they vote me down, unfix it plz... halp!!!

Comment: @Sha - no idea. That page is managed by HR...

Comment: btw cache expired.

Comment: Memory: checks out. Phew.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Eh? http://stackexchange.com/users/4540164/natalie-how?tab=accounts

Comment: @Adam right, but no activity at all which led me to think the accounts were created for her when joining SE as employee.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That is correct. Everyone gets an account + MSE profile because internal chat requires it.